# Type defined in template use to define template method of the class

Tags: c++, class, templates

There is a sample of the code:

```
template <class T>
class CMessage
    {
    public:
        using message_ptr = typename std::shared_ptr<T>;
        static message_ptr Create (T val)
            {
            return std::make_shared<T>(val);
            }
    };

class CBuilder
    {
    public:
        template <typename MT> MT::message_ptr CreateMessage()
            {
            return MT::message_ptr();
            }
    };

CBuilder builder;
CMessage<int>::message_ptr msg = builder.CreateMessage<CMessage<int>>();
```

CBuilder clsss is correct? It is possible to use MT::message_ptr in CBuilder?

Comment: _"CBuilder clsss is correct?"_ What's your compilers opinion?

Comment: It builds ok if you put `typename` before `MT::message_ptr` : https://ideone.com/gQHPHu

Comment: Please describe your problem more clearly.  Is there a compiler error?  If so, include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write "MT::message_ptr", you actually write an expression that depends on the definition of your parameter template (MT): that's called a dependent expression.

The problem for the compiler then is to know whether "message_ptr" is a type name or a name for something else (a function, a variable...). To solve this problem, the standard requires that any dependent expression for a type-name is prefixed by the the keyword... *typename* :-)

So here is the correct definition for your member function template:

```
template <typename MT> 
typename MT::message_ptr CreateMessage()
{
    return typename MT::message_ptr();
}
```

**EDIT**

BTW, "std::shared_ptr<T>" is not a dependent expression, so you *must not* use the keyword "typename" there. Simply write:

```
using message_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
```